# How to JQuery Drap and drop multiple/update msg on drop

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a project - simple game, so far I can drag and drop but i need the same draggable image to - when dropped - update display in drop div...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="game/js/jquery1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="game/js/jquery-ui1.8.min.js"></script>

    $( init );

function init() {
      $('#drag').draggable( {
                    containment: '#content',
                    cursor: 'move',
                    snap: '#content',
                    revert: true
                })

      $('#drop').droppable( {
             drop: handleDropEvent
      } )

    }

function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
  var draggable = ui.draggable;
  //Replace Image....
  var Num = 5;
  Num--;
         $(this).html('<img src="game/images/watermelon_-'+Num+'.png">').data(

  );

    //Call php Game->points(); to up points...
}
```

Comment: What is problem then in Your code ?

Comment: I want it to update drop msg ".html('...+Num+'..). I have 5 images i want to be displayed in series upon each drop... I've been search for whole week last week.

Comment: improve your english ,Indian

Comment: foreach drop
display image[$N]

Meaning upon every drop of dragged image, i want JQuery to N-- image number and add/update display image for successful drop...

Comment: Are you really implementing in your own project or just Wasting Developers time like us? You better speak proper english

Comment: Partik, if you do not want to help me then dont. thank you

Comment: Welcome And just look at your reputation "1" great ,please dont come in Development field ,goto Testing